# How do I concatenate one word with all elements of a list in R barplot title?

Tags: r

This is the code I'm currently running:

```
n <- 7
N <- 52
r <- 13
reps <- 1000000
deck <- rep(c('h','d','c','s'), each = r)

diamonds <- rep(NA, length.out = reps)
pos <- sample(x = 1:52, size = 7, replace = FALSE)
for(i in 1:reps) {
  hand <- sample(x = deck, replace = FALSE)[pos]
  diamonds[i] <- sum(ifelse(hand == 'd', 1, 0))
}
barplot(table(diamonds), col = 'red', xlab = '# of diamonds',
        ylab = paste('frequency out of',reps,'trials'),
        main = paste('Positions:',pos[1],pos[2],pos[3],pos[4],
                     pos[5],pos[6],pos[7]))
```

What I'd really like is to be able to give a title to the barplot with something like the following

```
barplot(..., main = paste('Positions:',pos))
```

and have the title say "Positions: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7", where p1,p2,...,p7 are the elements of pos.

For anyone that's interested, this code randomly chooses 7 positions from 52 and then counts the number of diamonds ('d') within those 7 positions after each shuffle of the deck for 1000000 shuffles. Then the empirical distribution of the number of diamonds within those 7 cards is plotted.

Comment: Unrelated to your questions, but you probably should initialize `diamonds` to be numeric, NA is logical by default and so your vector is coerced on the first diamonds[i] assignment: 

    diamonds <- rep(as.numeric(NA), length.out = reps)

Comment: Another unrelated to question `sum(ifelse(hand == 'd', 1, 0))` works the same as `sum(hand == 'd')` (`TRUE` is converted to `1`, `FALSE` to `0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collapse` in `paste` to collapse the multiple elements in a vector containing the base test and `pos`,

```
paste(c('Positions:', pos), collapse=" ")
```

Otherwise, when you paste "Positions:" to `pos` you get the former recycled to the length of `pos`.

Comment: Another way: `paste(c('Positions:', pos), collapse=" ")`